# How do I enable the console without it popping up on startup?

Tags: dota-2

I wanted to enable the console, so I Googled how to do it and found that I could do it by putting `-console` in the launch options of the game. I did that, but now the console opens every time I start Dota 2. Is there a way to have it open if I push <kbd>`</kbd>, but not whenever I start the game up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Go to `…\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg\` and create a new file called `autoexec.cfg` next to `config.cfg`, [so it won't get overwritten](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/what-is-this-autoexec-cfg-and-what-does-it-do). Open it and add a line that says `con_enable "1"`. That will enable the console even without adding `-console` to the launch settings.

Alternatively, you could add `hideconsole` to the configuration file to hide the console after it pops up, but I recommend the first method.

Comment: This is a bad solution because the config gets overwritten on dota startup. the safer solution is to put that code into a autoexec.cfg so it is written into config on every startup.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/why-is-an-autoexec-cfg-used-in-steam-games/152891#152891

Comment: @Wandang: Fixed.

Comment: I have just added ```-console -hideconsole``` in launch options and it enables the console but it is closed when game starts.. win win without having to dig into the folders )))

Answer (score 4):

Put `+con_enable 1` into your launch options. The `+` makes it untouchable for the autoexec. It's the most elegant solution for your problem.