# Can the Dota 2 hotkey labels be hidden?

Tags: dota-2, keyboard

I just bought myself a Razer Tartarus, and i've mapped it up to what seems most sensible for dota and then arranged dota's hotkeys as appropriate.

Now I just need to train my muscle memory from the keyboard to the keypad, however, the hotkey labels on spells and quick cast is misleading my easily distracted brain.

Is there a way (via console maybe?) to hide the hotkey labels on spells etc?

Comment: I am quite certain that you can't, it's part of the main body of the code. However, in case there is such a command, you can look around here: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands Unfortunately, due to the lack of time, I have not yet had the opportunity to look through everything, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of hotkeys you want to hide.

Go to *config.cfg* and copy each line that has `bind "KEY" ...` with your relevant keys. Paste all of these lines into *userconfig.cfg*.

Then remove all those key bindings in the game's settings, by clicking and then right-clicking.

Comment: I would be grateful if someone expanded this answer (e.g. explain where those config files are, and test if that `";thing"` is needed, or maybe even adding another "no-op" command would be required), because I really should be studying :P

Comment: the semicolon seperates commands. therefore `bind "key" ";command"` would execute nothing and then the "command". It is unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. (This is basically BlaXpirit's approach but without the modification since it is unneeded)

Bindings that are done via a config file will not be shown in the game (the hotkey square is emtpy as if no hotkey was selected) but still apply.

To do this you need to go to your dota folder `dota 2 beta\dota\cfg\` and create a file called `autoexec.cfg`. This file will be automatically loaded on startup from DotA2. (more on what autoexec is here: [What is this autoexec.cfg, and what does it do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/what-is-this-autoexec-cfg-and-what-does-it-do))

Next thing to do is opening config.cfg and copying everything containing `bind` into the autoexec.cfg. After this you need to delete the old ingame bindings by going into the ingame settings menu, leftclicking on a binding and then rightclicking it leaving it empty.

The next time you start DotA2 the bindings from autoexec.cfg will be loaded automatically and this will result in blank ingame hotkeys. (I assume this is what you wanted)