# Can you turn off denying?

Tags: dota-2

In the original dota there were many game modes that could be activated using commands at the start of the game. Among these I remember one that basically made it so you either couldn't deny, or so there was no point in doing so. Can this be done somehow in Dota 2? Can you turn off denying or render it useless in dota 2?

IE: My friend likes dota, but hates the concept of denying, so I'm trying to find out if this is possible to help give him motivation to play.

Comment: This can probably be achieved via console commands, but I do not know for sure. Note: Do not mess with console commands without knowing what you are doing - you may end up having to re-install DoTA 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr :** No, DotA 2 doesn't support yet custom game mode.

DotA 2 is a full online game (Appart for some tournament where players play on local lobby). This means that the game settings are set on Valve's server and thus can not be changed. Either you play All Pick, Captain's Mode or ARDM you can not turn off deny when playing matchmaking. Even if you create a private lobby, there are no option implemented at the moment that allows such thing.

However, with the release of Source 2 coming early 2015, DotA 2 is on the way to fully support custom games modes which could lead to DotA games where denying is turned off. Still this would not be an official DotA game and you might not find many players to play with you.

That being said, learning to deny is a concept inner to DotA. If your friend has trouble denying he can use the folowing command *dota_force_right_click_attack "1"* which makes denying a lot easier since you can right click to deny and are not longer required to press the *Attack* key then select the creep you want to deny (This command can be written in an [autoexec.cfg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/what-is-this-autoexec-cfg-and-what-does-it-do/152891#152891) file so you don't have to type it everytime you start the game. If it's the whole concept of denying that is the issue then I'm afraid there is not much more you can do, denying is a part of DotA and is a very interesting game mechanic. It can help you control your lane (if you want to push or not), it forces you to decide if you want to commit for a tower kill or if you let it being denied, you can even do some clutch plays and deny allies when they are low life thus denying some much needed XP and Gold to the enemy team.

Comment: I agree with your last paragraph, however my friend feels differently, and honestly I don't neccesarily blame him. Denying can be fun, it adds new strategy, but sometimes you don't wanna 'try that hard' if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Ender try Heroes of the Storm! There is no denying in it. That's why I prefer it.

Comment: I understand that and sadly that's how dota is. In my opinion it takes a lot of time before having fun in dota because the learning curve is so stiff and the many mechanics are overwhelming at first. Maybe heroes of the storm could be an alternative, I can't speak for LoL since I've not played it (and my hearth belongs to DotA)

Comment: For the sake of completion, my friend and I play LoL and Heroes, I just want to re-add dota to the list. (we played back when Dota was a Warcraft mod)

Comment: well then don't complain..just play dota with your friends and decide your role..if you will play with team then sure you will find fun and about denying..it will be great if you will deny more then the enemy team..go and try once..you will love it..