# How do I talk in all chat while drafting?

Tags: dota-2

While drafting there's a built-in chat box, so I can't hit Shift+Enter to bring up all chat. I've seen people still use all chat somehow though. How does one use all chat during drafting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it in the GUI. As you've seen it is possible, but you have to use the console.

First, you have to [have the console enabled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152812/how-do-i-enable-the-console-without-it-popping-up-on-startup). Then just hit <kbd>`</kbd>, or whatever the console is set as and type `say <message>`.

Comment: Yes, this is currently the only way to do it.

Comment: +1 Always wondered about this, never bothered to find out.